# Prevent FONT Tag in execCommand

Tags: html, css, fonts

How can I somehow "configure" in execCommand, so that I do not see the next element?

[Font Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxctP.png)

`<font color="xxxxxxx"></font>`

Well, the problem is that I am creating a simple editor for a project and I can not create the CSS correctly, I could do it with CSS, but that tag does not help me, is there any way to solve this?

The other problem is that I have no possibility to do something like this

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Because it puts me like this

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>

<p>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

As I mentioned, it is an editor with execCommand and an IFRAME

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact same problem and I solved it by removing font tags when I manage the list.

Just wrote something like that :

```
$("font").contents().unwrap();
```

Hope it can help you.